# Libre Office Base error while creating new DB

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice-base

I have Libre Office 4.3, recently installed 5.1 (thought it would help). On top of that I have java oracle 7 and 1.8.0 java openjdk. Whenever I try to create a new db via the db wizard, in all cases i get the same errors:

```
The connection to the data source "New Database" could not be established.
```

and

```
SQL Status: S1000
Error code: -27

file input/output error java.lang.NullPointerException.properties /home/haris/Documents/data_base/New Database.odb
```

In Tools>Options>Advanced "Use a java time enviroment" is ticked, JRE already installed: Sun Microsystem Inc. 1.6.0_39 Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_91 Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_80

Now i386 stands for 32-bit right? which is what i have for all of the above

In class path i pressed "add folder" and added 1.8 openjdk, but still get the same 2 errors.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Can anyone point me to the right direction for solving this, because it's of the outmost importance for me to refresh my db skills

Comment: "Whenever I try to create a new db" -- I assume you mean the `Create a new database: Embedded database: HSQLDB Embedded` option.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some sort of installation problem.  The normal thing to do would be to reinstall the packages or maybe upgrade the whole operating system.  12.04 sounds pretty old, even though since it's an LTS it is still supported.

However, I would try something else first.  The best way to use LO Base is with a split database setup rather than an embedded setup.  So for example, install MySQL, then in the Base setup wizard, choose `Connect to an existing database`.  This will be **much** more stable.

See also https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#So_why_should_I_avoid_.27embedded_databases.27.3F.